# Remove values from subarrays javascript

Tags: javascript

Having some difficulty removing the row 0 in all my subarrays

Tried splice as well but can't seem to find a good example that remove values from subarrays.

**Arr1**

```
// This is how my main Arr1 looks like
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), ...]
0: (2) ["2021-07-06T00:00:00Z", {…}]
1: (2) ["2021-07-06T00:00:00Z", {…}]
...

// Which will have multiple subarrays when the main array is expanded
0: Array(2)
0: "2021-07-06T00:00:00Z"
1: {type: "meeting", id: "123"}

1: Array(2)
0: "2021-07-06T00:00:00Z"
1: {type: "call", id: "456"}

....
```

**End result** - Remove row 0, which is the date & time from each array and combine all of them together

```
0: {type: "meeting", id: "123"}
1: {type: "call", id: "456"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
let result = [];
let arr = [
    ["2021-07-06T00:00:00Z", {type:"meeting",id:"123"}],
    ["2021-07-06T00:00:00Z", {type: "call", id: "456"}]
];
result = arr.map((item)=>{
    return item[1];
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doing a push inside a `forEach` means you probably should be using `map()`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have nested arrays you will have to combine map and filter. Map to iterate the top level and filter or splice (depending on your logic) - on the sub to remove or filter out items.

`topArray.map(subArray => subArray.filter(item => ...))`

**or**

`topArray.map(subArray => subArray.splice(start, deleteCount)`

If you then want to "flatten" the results you can add .flat() or .flatMap() to the end (depending on your logic)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

---

If you know that you just want to grab the first item on each sub-array, you can:

`topArray.map(subArray => subArray[0])`

Answer (score 2):

I would personnaly recommand using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which here takes for each element in your array, the second element (which is your **object**)

```js
const arr = [
    ["2021-07-06T00:00:00Z", {type:"meeting",id:"123"}],
    ["2021-08-06T00:00:00Z", {type: "call", id: "456"}],
    ["2021-09-06T00:00:00Z", {type: "zoom", id: "789"}]
];

console.log(arr.map(item => item[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `slice` to remove the first element of each subarray. And a `flatMap` to join all the filtered subarrays into one single array.

Here's how I would do it:

```
const filteredArray = array.flatMap((subarray) => subarray.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

use Map with filter

```
var a = [[1,2], [3,4]]

console.log(a.map((b) => b.filter((c, i) => i != 0)))
```

Result

```
[[2], [4]]
```